# Azure Release Pipeline -- ACI Deployment -- 403 Forbidden error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, azure-active-directory, azure-container-instances

Couple of months back I explored Azure Devops and implemented an MLOPs solution from setting up the infra to running the training and deployment through Azure Devops. The communication between Azure Devops and Azure ML studio happened through Service Principals and other parameters within the Azure Devops pipeline. It was successful back then.

**Below is the ACI Script:**

`az ml model deploy -g $(azureml.resourceGroup) -w $(azureml.workspaceName) --lo $(azureml.location) --mr 1000 -n $(service.name.staging) -f ../metadata/model.json --dc aciDeploymentConfigStaging.yml --ic inferenceConfig.yml --overwrite`

**Below is the aciDeploymentConfigStaging.yml:**

`--- containerResourceRequirements:   cpu: 1   memoryInGB: 1 computeType: ACI`

**Below is the inferenceConfig.yml:**

`entryScript: score.py runtime: python condaFile: scoringConfig.yml extraDockerfileSteps: schemaFile: sourceDirectory: enableGpu: False baseImage: baseImageRegistry:`

**Below is the score.py:**

```
import json
import numpy
import joblib
import time
from azureml.core.model import Model`



def init():
    global LGBM_MODEL
    model_path = Model.get_model_path("retail_model")
    LGBM_MODEL = joblib.load(model_path)
    print("model initialized" + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))


def run(raw_data, request_headers):
    data = json.loads(raw_data)\["data"\]
    data = numpy.array(data)
    result = LGBM_MODEL.predict(data)

    info = {
        "input": raw_data,
        "output": result.tolist()
      }
    print(json.dumps(info))

    print(('{{"RequestId":"{0}", '
            '"TraceParent":"{1}", '
            '"NumberOfPredictions":{2}}}'
      ).format(
            request_headers.get("X-Ms-Request-Id", ""),
            request_headers.get("Traceparent", ""),
            len(result)
    ))

    return {"result": result.tolist()}
```

I wanted to re-attempt this to see if a monitoring and data drift triggers can be included using Azure Logic Apps. So I ran the pipeline for CI again and it was successful. But however, the problem occurs in the release pipeline, especially when I want to deploy it to Azure Container Instance(ACI). Please note I have a model that has been trained and registred using the CI pipeline.

**Below is the error that I am receiving:**

"2023-07-03T03:25:51.9257033Z {
2023-07-03T03:25:51.9257153Z     "error": {
2023-07-03T03:25:51.9259105Z         "message": "Received bad response from Model Management Service:\nResponse Code: 403\nHeaders: {'Date': 'Mon, 03 Jul 2023 03:25:51 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'd23e26ae-ef4b-413c-a988-9a16a64dd24e', 'x-ms-client-session-id': '9cef5311-5d76-40da-a6ea-69a9cdb7f9a3', 'api-supported-versions': '1.0, 2018-03-01-preview, 2018-11-19', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'x-aml-cluster': 'vienna-eastus-02', 'x-request-time': '1.213', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}\nContent: b'{"code":"Forbidden","statusCode":403,"message":"Forbidden","details":[{"code":"UserError","message":"KeyVaultErrorException encountered. Operation returned an invalid status code \'Forbidden\' Please try the \'Resync Keys\' action."}],"correlation":{"RequestId":"d23e26ae-ef4b-413c-a988-9a16a64dd24e"}}'"
2023-07-03T03:25:51.9260433Z     }
2023-07-03T03:25:51.9260551Z }}
"

Any suggestions around this would be helpful. I tried running this with a difference Service principal and i get the same error. Also the same service principal was used in the CI pipeline and there was no issue.